# Gstreamer picture-in-picture - two files playing in parallel

Tags: gstreamer, pipeline, picture-in-picture

I need to compose a pipeline for "picture-in-picture" effect to combine media from two files:

1) video content from the first file is showed on the full window 
  2) video from the second file is resized and is showed in the top-left corner of a window,
  3) audio from both files mixed 
  4) the content from both files should be played simultaneously

So far I got the following pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e \
  filesrc name="src0" location=$FILE0 \
    ! decodebin name="decodebin0" ! queue ! videoscale ! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw,width=120" ! videoconvert ! videomixer.sink_0  decodebin0. ! queue ! audioconvert ! audiomixer.sink_0 \
  filesrc name="src1" location=$FILE1 \
    ! decodebin name="decodebin1" ! queue ! videoscale ! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw" ! videoconvert ! videomixer.sink_1  decodebin1. ! queue ! audioconvert ! audiomixer.sink_1 \
   videomixer name="videomixer" ! autovideosink \
   audiomixer name="audiomixer" ! autoaudiosink
```

However, it plays streams one by one, not in parallel. Does anyone know what should be changed here in order to play streams simultaneously ?

Ps: attaching the diagram of this pipeline visualized: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly - the order of the sources in the pipeline does matter - after slight modification of the pipeline and placing the source with "larger" frame on the first place I was able to get the result as expected:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -ev \
  filesrc name="src1" location=$FILE1 \
   ! decodebin name="decodebin1" ! queue ! videoscale ! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw,framerate=15/1" ! videoconvert ! videomixer.sink_1  decodebin1. ! queue ! audioconvert name="ac1" \
  filesrc name="src0" location=$FILE0 \
   ! decodebin name="decodebin0" ! queue ! videoscale ! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw,width=120,framerate=15/1" ! videoconvert ! videomixer.sink_0  decodebin0. ! queue ! audioconvert name="ac0"\
   ac0. ! audiomixer.sink_0 \
   ac1. ! audiomixer.sink_1 \
  videomixer name="videomixer" ! autovideosink \
  audiomixer name="audiomixer" ! autoaudiosink \
```